# PHP capturing radio buttons into .txt

Tags: php

I have this code that I have to input data into a .txt file.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fullname']) && $_POST['fullname'] != '' &&            isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
$user = $_POST['fullname'];
$pass =  $_POST['email'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host =  gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$log_file = fopen('log7984131947.txt','a+');
$log_text = $user.'<b>:</b>'.$pass.'<b>:</b>'.$ip.'<b>:</b>'.$host."\r\n";
fwrite($log_file,$log_text);
header('Location: '.`enter code here`$redirect);
} else {
?>
```

I need it to be used with this data on my page.  I have tried everything I can google but I am php illiterate and need some help.I need to keep the ip address and hostname but just need to add the Name and Radio buttons that I have.  I don't need the course.

```
<tr>
    <td>Full Name: </td>
    <td><input name="fullname" id="name" type="text" size="20" maxlength="80"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Course:</td>
    <td>Phishing Basics</td>
</tr>
<div class="field form-inline radio">
<label class="radio" for="txtContact">Did you find this training helpful?</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio" value="yes" /> <span>Yes</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="radio" value="no" /> <span>No</span>
</div>
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Proceed &gt; &gt;"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fullname']) && $_POST['fullname'] != '' &&            isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') {
    $user = $_POST['fullname'];
    $pass =  $_POST['email'];
    $radio =  $_POST['radio'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $host =  gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $log_file = fopen('log7984131947.txt','a+');
    $log_text = $user.'<b>:</b>'.$pass.'<b>:</b>'.$ip.'<b>:</b>'.$host.'<b>:</b>'.$radio."\r\n";
    fwrite($log_file,$log_text);
    header('Location: '.`enter code here`$redirect);
} else {
?>
```

unless you want to name "radio" (the `<input name="..."` value in your HTML) to something more meaningful.

Comment: This did not work...it still went to Server Error 500...i changed the $_POST['email'] to $_POST['radio'] because I do not have an email in this script